# Only one ActiveMQ session is handling messages

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms, consumer

In a project, I am using ActiveMQ to process a relatively large number of messages. For that purpose there is a queue, `fooQueue`, which contains the messages to be processed.

Two instances of an application are processing messages from that queue, using Spring JMS. I have a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` set up in the following way.

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
container.setDestinationName(QUEUE_NAME);
container.setMessageListener(myMessageListener);
container.setConcurrency(getProperty("concurrency"));
container.setSessionTransacted(true);
container.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());
return container;
```

By looking at the AMQ web console, I can confirm that the correct number of consumers and sessions are created (session/consumer). However, it appears as if one session is doing most job, which leads to the application being frozen at times.

That session enqueues and dequeues most messages, all others far less then it. If I restart one of those two application instances, one session in the app instance picks up the work, and behaves the same.

Besides checking if `myMessageListener` is blocking, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: How is your transaction management defined? I had a similar issue where sending a bunch of messages blocked reading messages using the same connectionFactory while it was sending, turned out to be that the message sending was done in one large and long-running transaction.

Comment: Good hint. I will have to check it, but I have already seen a few threads waiting for transactions to be committed. How did you resolve your problem? Separate connections for receiving and sending?

Comment: I solved it by having one transaction per message send instead of one large one. The transactions also did some JPA stuff..

Comment: Could you give me a hint on how to accomplish that, if you were using Spring JMS? Didn't find anything obvious when googling for it.:/

Comment: I was using sping jmstemplate and spring `@Transactional`, so basically moved the `@Transactional` annotation further down call chain.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give it a try then.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tried various settings, increasing the memory, using separate KahaDB instances for every queue etc. but nothing helped. What helped was to split the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [prefetch](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) settings on your consumers and how it works.  This sounds as though you are starting one instance and it is grabbing a large chunk of messages from the Queue before the others get a chance to.  Lowering the prefetch value will lead to a more fair distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Prefetch is set to 0, which makes the problem a bit more misterious.:S